# Search OOP - Model design (MVC)

Tags: php, model-view-controller, oop, class, model

I want to create a class of "Search" in the model (MVC / framework), I want to know how the method should be structured.

There are two type of search and the SQL query contain a few JOIN.

This will allow customer to type postcode, company name or city from ONE search text box:

```
SELECT * FROM Shop as S
   JOIN shop_options as O on O.ShopID = S.ShopID
   JOIN shop_openhours as OH on OH.ShopID = S.ShopID
WHERE (O.postcode = :postcode  OR S.company LIKE :companyName OR S.city = :townName)
```

If customer visit specific town by url, eg: /town/London

Then the query would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Shop as S
   JOIN shop_options as O on O.ShopID = S.ShopID
   JOIN shop_openhours as OH on OH.ShopID = S.ShopID
WHERE S.city = :townName
```

The data will need to be manipulate in the model to find out if the shop is open or closed.

Here the quick design I come up with:

```
class modelSearch extends Model {

    public $id;
    public $shopName;
    public $isOpen = false;

    public static function findAll($searchType) {
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM Shop as S
                 JOIN shop_options as O on O.ShopID = S.ShopID
                 JOIN shop_openhours as OH on OH.ShopID = S.ShopID
               WHERE (O.postcode = :postcode  OR S.company LIKE :companyName OR S.town = :townName)";

         //fetch data into $data

        $search = array();
        foreach ($Dbdata as $data) {
            $searchModel = new modelSearch();
            $searchModel->isOpen = modelSearch::isShopOpen($data['opentime'], $data['closetime']);
            $searchModel->id = $data['id'];
            $searchModel->shopName = $data['shopName'];

            $search[] = $searchModel;
        }
        return $search;
    }

    public static function findByTown($search) {
        //Same code as findAll() apart from SQL query (WHERE)
        //WHERE S.town = :townName
    }

    public static function isShopOpen($open, $close) {
        $min = ($open > 123) ? $open : 345; // Earliest allow time
        if ($close < $min)
        //some block code here
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Im I on the right path or what can be improved?

Comment: does it work? what are you looking for in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, this is not the right way yet.  Static functions are procedural code wrapped in a class.  Take out all of the static and it will look a lot more like OOP, although OOP is really about the interaction of objects that you create.  Calling one method after the other to achieve what you want is just a fancy way of writing functions.

Here is what I'd do:

```
class modelSearch extends Model {

   /**** public variables should not be common in OOP.  We want to control
    **** the interface.  Someone could change these if they were left public.
    ****/
   private $id;
   private $shopName;
   private $isOpen = false;

   public function __construct($shopName)
   {
      $this->shopName = $shopName;
   }

    public function findAll($searchType) {
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM Shop as S
                 JOIN shop_options as O on O.ShopID = S.ShopID
                 JOIN shop_openhours as OH on OH.ShopID = S.ShopID
               WHERE (O.postcode = :postcode  OR S.company LIKE :companyName OR S.town = :townName)";


        /**** There is no need to instantiate any more objects in the class to
     **** do the work. I am replacing the rest of your function with
     **** pseudo-code.
     ****/
    $data = execution_of_sql();

    // I am not clear on what you want.
        foreach ($data as $record) {
       if ($this->isShopOpen($record['opentime'], $record['closetime']))
       {
          $openShops[] = array('id' => $record['id'],
                   'name' => $record['shopName']);
       }
    }

    return $openShops;

    // **** Notice how there is no need to instantiate another object
    // **** because we are the object.
    // $searchModel = new modelSearch();

    }

    // **** These could possibly be joined into 1 function with more parameters.
    public function findByTown($search) {
        //Same code as findAll() apart from SQL query (WHERE)
        //WHERE S.town = :townName
    }


    // **** protected and private hide information so that you can ignore it
    // **** outside the class.  The interface to the class is now less
    // **** cluttered.
    protected function isShopOpen($open, $close) {
        $min = ($open > 123) ? $open : 345; // Earliest allow time
        if ($close < $min)
        //some block code here
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a good start.  Even better would be to wrap the database calls in a repository that implements an interface.  That way, the model doesn't know about HOW a search is actually conducted, and the repository could be used with any backing DB.  All the model would have to do is delegate to the repo's search methods.  In PHP, a repository that wrapped a PDO object would likely be the ideal choice.

Comment: Agreed, its hard to write that in a non-scary way though.

Comment: @kevinmajor1 are you referring like db class? I have already implemented this and use PDO :)

Comment: Yes.  Your models shouldn't execute or even create SQL directly.  What they should do is contain a reference (read: private data member) to a repository that does all of that dirty work for the model.  Take your findAll() method: it should really have only a few lines, at most.  One to delegate to the repository, one to return the results, and some defensive error handling/anticipating code.  The whole point is to separate concerns - your model should not be concerned with the nuts-and-bolts SQL needed to obtain result sets from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,You are in the right way.Follow one MVC framework.I think you are following one frame work for this.You are created one class Search as Model and also have controller and view.